# Using SWT Accessible Screenreader sometimes ignore my String from getName

Tags: java, swt, screen-readers, nvda, jaws-screen-reader

Different screen readers (VoiceOver, NVDA, Narrator) ignore my code on different locations of the UI. The method `getName(AccessibleEvent e)` gets called and supplies the correct result, yet it sometimes is ignored by either VoiceOver, NVDA or Narrator. This behaviour seems so random.

The following case is working with VoiceOver, yet NVDA completely ignores it.

```
Accessible accessible = getControlForAccesible().getAccessible();
accessible.addAccessibleListener(new AccessibleAdapter() {

    @Override
    public void getName(AccessibleEvent e) {
        e.result = getTextForScreenReader();
    }

});
```

This code is inside a subclass of `Composite` which acts as button in my case. So there is no subview inside this button. I draw the text with the `drawText`-method of `GC`. It also attached a tooltip to the composite which is ignored as well.

No matter which of the methods of the `AccessibleAdapter` i use, still the same result, whereas on some other parts of my code, those different methods supply different results.

Does anyone had similar problems?

Comment: Ok apparently `Composites` are ignored by certain Screen Readers (e.g. Narrator or NVDA) if there is no Label inside that contains text. I added a label with a whitespace character and it the screen readers read the text that was drawn onto the `Composite` aswell as the text inside my label, but only if i hovered the label. On just hovering the `Composite` nothing happens at all.